# Using 2d array in a class

Tags: c++, object, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm having a few problems.

1) It says declaration of 'matrix' as 2d array must have bounds (**mPoint in header file).  Why? I want it to be dynamic, how can I fix it?

2) Another problem is "mPoint" isn't declared in this scope, in (Square_Matrix::Set_Size) in the .cpp file.

3) Lastly it says the definition in the destructor (Square_Matrix::~Square_Matrix) is implicitly declared.

Nothing in my c++ book seems to answer my questions.

```
//header file
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Square_Matrix
{
public:
   int **mPoint;
   int N;
   Square_Matrix();
   ~Square_Matrix();
   void Set_Size (int new_size);
};



//.cpp file
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Square_Matrix.h"


Square_Matrix::Square_Matrix()
{
    mPoint = new int*[0];
    mPoint[0] = new int[0];
    N = 0;
}

Square_Matrix::~Square_Matrix()   //destructor
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        delete [] mPoint[i];
    }
    delete [] mPoint;
}

void Square_Matrix::Set_Size (int new_size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){ //deallocates memory if there's already a matrix
        delete [] mPoint[i];
    }
    delete [] mPoint;

    N = new_size;
    mPoint = new int*[new_size];    //create dynamic 2d array of size new_size
    for (int i = 0; i < new_size; i++){
        mPoint[i] = new int[new_size];
    }
}
```

Comment: `matrix` does not exist in your code at all.  Did you forget to post some code?  The last error is because you did not include a declaration of the destructor in your class definition.

Comment: Nope, that's all the code.  There's no variable matrix anywhere, I thought c++ somehow knew I'm trying to make a matrix

Comment: New errors: (1) new types may not be defined in a return type, (2) error: return type specification for constructor invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not declare the destructor in your class definition. So the compiler implicitly declared it. However then you define the destructor explicitly yourself. You may not do that.

In the constructor you did not initialize mPoint. So your code in for example function Set_Size has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Okay that got rid of all the errors, but I'm getting new ones. error: new types may not be defined ina  return type, note: perhaps a semicolon is missing after the definition of square_matrix.  It also says return type specification for constructor is invalid (I updated my code in my first post)

Comment: @Foxic Maybe. But I do not see the code you are speaking about now.

Comment: I changed Square_Matrix::Square_Matrix() and put the destructor into the header file, not sure why it's not updating for you.  Edit: Do you see my changes in my original post yet?

Comment: @Foxic I do not see where the constructor has a return type.

Comment: Exactly, I have no idea why it's happening

Comment: @Foxic It can be if the header file after the class definition contains some other incorrect declarations and the cpp module starts with the constructor definition.

Comment: I posted all of my code in my post so that's all the declarations I have.

Comment: @Foxic The code you posted has no such an error. Check whether you have some comments in the header or in the module that formed incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Square_Matrix::Square_Matrix()
{
    mPoint = new int*[0];
    mPoint[0] = new int[0];
    N = 0;
}
```

You do not want to do that, and it is not valid.  Just set the value of `mPoint` to `nullptr`.  You cannot allocate an array of size 0.

```
Square_Matrix::Square_Matrix() : mPoint(nullptr), N(0)
{
}
```

Comment: Didn't get rid of the new errors. (1) new types may not be defined in a return type,  (2) error: return type specification for constructor invalid,  (3) 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope)

Comment: If `nullptr` is not found, it means you are using an older compiler.  Replace it with `NULL` or `0`.  Show your complete and updated code and errors with line numbers.